# Como controlar a navegação do DataGridView, sem o foco sair do Campo Texto de Pesquisar ? C#

Tags: c#, query, firebird, datagridview, texto

Estou trabalhando em um formulário de consulta, e um cliente me solicitou o seguinte desafio. É navegar nos registros da pesquisa do DataGrid sem perder o foco no campo Texto pesquisar ? Trabalho com Banco de Dados[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcyXI.png) Firebird.

Answer (score -2):

O que vc pode fazer é manter o foco no grid se o usuario pressionar as teclas direcionais, do contrario qualquer outra tecla pressionada vc leva o foco pro textbox.